# twitter bootstrap responsive menu randomly does not collapse after menu selection

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap responsive for a mobile app built using Brightcove App Cloud. When the menu collapses on narrow devices it will eventually fail to collapse after a menu selection.  The content below the menu will change, but the menu does not collapse.  I have tried to isolate it to one HTML page, or menu item position, but can't see a pattern.

Here is the pertinent code from my files (which are basically the same for six pages, outside of some specific CSS):

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="bc-manifest" content="manifest.json" />
    <title>Zencoder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://files.brightcove.com/proxima-nova/font-faces.css">
    <link href="stylesheets/brightcove-app-cloud-1.12.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/allPagesStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/zencoder.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>

<section id="pageone" class="page">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav maintop app-navigation">
              <li id="mainNavTargetS"><a class="ss-nav">System Status</a></li>
              <li id="mainNavTargetBC"><a class="bc-nav">Brightcove</a></li>
              <li id="mainNavTargetVC"><a class="vc-nav">Video Cloud</a></li>
              <li id="mainNavTargetAC"><a class="ac-nav">App Cloud</a></li>
              <li class="active" id="mainNavTargetZC"><a class="zc-nav">Zencoder</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
      </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </header>
```

Thanks for helping out with this (at least to me) perplexing problem.

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used the code from the tutorial listed.  And this was my problem.  Note that in the tutorial the menu display button for a collapsed menu appears as follows.

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>
```

If you check the actual Twitter Bootstrap code it appears as follows (with a button, not an anchor)

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

As I first started on the code this made no difference, but as I started to change styles problems began to appear.  Those problems disappeared once I matched the original Bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will give you an idea where you are wrong. Also you need jQuery and bootbootstrap js.

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/319_bootstrap_pills_tabs/Tabs-Pills-BEGIN/navbar-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you don't have any other javascript looking for .collapse or any other javascript calling a collapse function.

I had previous code using a custom collapse function that I guess conflicted with Bootstrap.